# Html: Bootstrap form alignment in center

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a simple login system and I have some Front-End difficulties. I'm trying to make a center-based login form with some inputs and a button. So basically right now I was able to make few inputs inside the center, but when I tried adding a button, then I got result like this:[image]

- Note: I need the button to be in the center of the form. Also, am I doing the form in the center correctly?

My HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-header text-center apie_m_cga">~ Support Desk ~</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-md-offset-7 align-center ">
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="inputUsername6" placeholder="Username" class="form-control mx-sm-3 text-center">
        <br>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword6" placeholder="Password" class="form-control mx-sm-3 text-center">
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `text-align: center;` to your `form-group`

```css
.form-group {
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <h1 class="page-header text-center apie_m_cga">~ Support Desk ~</h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-md-offset-7">
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="inputUsername6" placeholder="Username" class="form-control mx-sm-3 text-center">
      <br>
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword6" placeholder="Password" class="form-control mx-sm-3 text-center">
      <br>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, but one more thing.. The button isn't really in the center or perhaps the inputs are maybe too long, because in the preview you can see some difference between the center of the button and inputs

Comment: @DzITC it *is* in the center. What you see is bootstrap's media queries on the inputs that's misbehaving.

Comment: OK, how can I make it to look a bit smoother?:D

Answer (score 2):

add text-center class to the div that contain form-group class:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-header text-center apie_m_cga">~ Support Desk ~</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="row justify-content-center ">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-md-offset-7 align-center text-center">
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="inputUsername6" placeholder="Username" class="form-control mx-sm-3 text-center">
        <br>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword6" placeholder="Password" class="form-control mx-sm-3 text-center">
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add .text-center add on parent DIV

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-header text-center apie_m_cga">~ Support Desk ~</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-md-offset-7 align-center text-center">
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="inputUsername6" placeholder="Username" class="form-control mx-sm-3 text-center">
        <br>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword6" placeholder="Password" class="form-control mx-sm-3 text-center">
        <br>
        <button type="button" class=" btn-primary btn-lg">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you make the button the same length with the input fields, it'll make the form look better.

Try this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-header text-center apie_m_cga">~ Support Desk ~</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-md-offset-7 align-center ">
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="inputUsername6" placeholder="Username" class="form-control text-center">
        <br>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword6" placeholder="Password" class="form-control col-12 text-center">
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn col-12 btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the class of your button "btn-lg" is influenced in position. Basically there is no any special errors on your script except for it.
Please remove it in class and try again

Comment: hey "btn-lg" just changes the size of button.